# Windows Boot Manager shows an operating system that is not installed

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot

I added a hdd to my laptop that already had Windows 7 on it.  I booted into it a couple times.  Then I formatted the hdd because I already have Windows 7 on my primary drive and just needed the new hdd for extra space.

Now when I boot, it says there are two operating systems, even when the one drive is formatted.  If I choose the operating system on the formatted drive, it errors saying "the device is inaccessible".  Booting into the primary drive OS works fine.

I booted from my windows 7 dvd, and even it says there are two operating systems still.

I would like there to be only one operating system detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Microsoft;

> Even if you delete or format the partition containing Windows 7, it
>   can still appear as an operating system option when you start your
>   computer. You can remove Windows 7 from the multiboot screen.

1. Open **System Configuration** by clicking the `Start` button, clicking `Control Panel`, clicking `System and Security`, clicking `Administrative Tools`, and then double-clicking `System Configuration`.‌ If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
2. Click the `Boot` tab, and then click the listing for ‍`Windows 7‍‍‍`.
3. Click `Delete`, click <kbd>OK</kbd>, and then click `Restart`.

Source - [Uninstall Windows 7 on a multiboot system](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/uninstall-windows-7-on-a-multiboot-system)